# JavaFX2 StackOverflowError at ObservableListWrapper

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to use a filter on a text field. The problem is I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError at
com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.size(ObservableListWrapper.java:335)
```

I can't understand why the exception is thrown, because I had similar code and there was no StackOverflowError. I think setText() is calling the listener again and again, but why there was no error on similar code that I did before?

```
public static void addNumericFilter(final TextField tf) {
    tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> value, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            //System.out.println("text = " + tf.getText());
            System.out.println("value = " + value.getValue());
            System.out.println("oldValue = " + oldValue);
            System.out.println("newValue = " + newValue);

            try {
                Integer.parseInt(value.getValue());
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                tf.setText(oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

This code works perfectly, for example (why there is not stack overflow here?):

```
public static void addUpperCaseFilter(final TextField tf) {
    tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> value, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            tf.setText(value.getValue().toUpperCase());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that when this happens, your `oldValue` is not a valid `Integer`, so the `Integer.parseInt` is failing continuously and causing an infinite loop of trying to parse it and then set it again.

Comment: I think Marc is correct. If you initialize the TextField to something value (e.g. `tf=new TextField("0");`) then it seems to work OK. If you initialize it to something invalid (`tf=new TextField();`) and the first thing you type is also invalid, then trouble ensues.